# localhost:8080 не найден

Tags: java, jsp, localhost

Суть в чем: создал *maven* проект и добавил поддержку *web*. При запуске *Tomcat* выдает ошибку

> http://localhost:8080/s
>
> Приложение не найдено

После этого сервер продолжает работать, в логах ошибки нет и я в ручную могу перейти на *jsp* и всё ок будет. Подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего эта ошибка и как её убрать?

[image: ![Ошибка при запуске приложения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzFmz.png)

вот код помника, пробовал разные варианты, этот по уроку делал:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupid</groupId>
<artifactId>projectName</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javaee</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

а документа web.xml нет потому, что я прочитал, если есть аннотация WebServlet("/"), то он не нужен

Comment: Добавьте файл web.xml в вопрос. Вообще переходить стоит указывая контекст localhost:8080/имяWar/запрос. Можете так же добавть скриншот страницы localhost:8080/manager это тоже поможет

Comment: скорее всего у вас неверная конфигурацияTomcat. Переинсталируете его и потом можно пользоваться. Только вот адрес такой вряд-ли будет работать, пока вы не скопируете ваше приложение в корневой каталог.

Comment: переустанавливал и Tomcat с 7 на 8 и идею не помогло

Comment: вы неправильно вводите адрес страницы, а поскольку показывать мапинг не хотите вам очень сложно помочь...

Answer (score 1):

У меня была точно такая же ошибка. Скорее всего у вас стоит в настройках томката браузер default, а в виндовсе нет браузера по умолчанию. Выставляете в настройках существующий браузер и всё будет ок. По крайней мере у меня было так.